# adding a sequence of numbers but possibly not closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series of sum from this piece of code which I want to come up with a formula in terms of n:

int fun(int n) {
int r = 0;
int q = 8*n;
for (int i=0; i<=q; i = i+4)
for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
r++;
return r;
}

So I have something like this:

i=0: 0

i=4: 1+2+3+4

i=8: 1+2+... +8

i=8n:1+2+... +8n

So I thought I have this series of sum:

$\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \frac{4i(i+1)}{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{2n}2i(i+1)= ....$

but I got kind of stuck to develop a close form sum in terms of n for the final sum. Could someone suggest what the sum would be in terms of n? is there closed form solution?

I am adding basically:
2x3 + 3x4 + 4x5 + ... + 2n(2n+1)

Comment: Believe me, you would have a degree-3 polynomial closed form. Think the following will help: $\sum_{i=0}^{n}i=n(n+1)/2$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n}i^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$

Comment: Also, if you want your code to match up your expression, r++ would be r=r+1+j.

Comment: Did you try that code at all ?

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop just adds $i$ to $r$, with $i$ running from $0$ to $4\cdot2n$ in steps $4$ by the outer loop.

Hence in the end,

$$r=4\frac{2n(2n+1)}2.$$